# Store Fields in an external database

Tags: 7, entities, database

I'm interfacing an external database with Drupal 7.  I have created custom entities and custom fields to represent the tables in the external database.  Is there a simple way to set the fields up so all CRUD uses the external database?

I still want to use Drupal's default field_sql_storage.module, but have it switch to the external database and back for these fields automatically.  Can I say "for this field, use this other database".

Something simple like:

```
function mymodule_field_info() {
  return array(
    'customfield' => array(
      'label' => t('My Custom Field'), 
      'description' => t('This field stores text in the external database.'), 
      'settings' => array('max_length' => 255), 
      'instance_settings' => array('text_processing' => 0), 
      'default_widget' => 'text_textfield', 
      'default_formatter' => 'text_default',
      // Simple setting to change database.
      'database' => 'externaldb', // From settings.php $database connections.
    ), 
}
```

The hard way is to create a custom storage backend and use it for these fields like the [Mongodb module](http://drupal.org/project/mongodb). I've tested this and it works, but it seems like there should be any easier way if you want to use Drupal's default field_sql_storage.module.

Would the strategic placement of db_set_active() allow me to avoid creating a full custom storage backend?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Field Storage API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/group/field_storage/7) you can use for external storage in fields.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid writing a whole storage module using Field Storage API. Drupal's default field_sql_storage.module works fine. I just want it to switch to a different database when interacting with my custom field.